# How to merge specific elements inside an array together?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, filter, foreach

I've been working on a personal project of making a calculator that inputs any string and if said string has a compute-able problem in it, solve it.

Right now I've been able to convert any string into a readable array that only contains numbers and operators.

My issue is once I have these arrays, such as `[5,5,3,4,'*',5,2]` I need them to be `[5534,*,52]`.

What would be the best way to tell the computer I want you to merge all elements of this array that are `typeof number` into one while keeping operators in place?

This is what I have now,

```
let array = ['1','b','c',1,2,'d','*',3]
let regex = /[0-9]/;
let reop = /[*/+-]/g;
let holder = [];

let filter = array.filter(function(x){
  if (regex.test(x) === true || reop.test(x)=== true) {
    return true
  } else null
})
filter.forEach(function(x){
  if (regex.test(x)===true) {
    holder.push(parseFloat(x));
  } else {holder.push(x)}
})
console.log(holder)
let holder1 = [];
let combine = holder.filter(function(x){
  if (regex.test(x)===true){
    console.log(holder.join(''))
  }
})
console.log(holder1)
```

in my example I would like holder1 to equal `[112,'*',3]`

Comment: What is an example of a string that you're entering and how do you end up with `[5,5,3,4,'*',5,2]`? Is the user entering in something like `"5534 * 52"`  ?

Comment: The string can be random, long as I can filter it into numbers and operators. That is a made up array as an example. I can turn strings into `[5,5,3,4,'*',5,2]` currently, but I cannot turn them into `[5534,*,52]` ... the idea being you can keyboard mash any string and get a return if possible.

Comment: Because I'm just thinking that it might be easier for you to split your string so that the numbers remain connected in the resulting array, rather than trying to connect/merge them afterwards.

Comment: Is there really no great way to merge these values afterwards? I figured it'd be the easiest approach to combine similar values. Let's say I null anything that isn't numbers or operators in string, and have something like you said. How would I make that into the array I want? `"5534 * 52"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join your array of elements into a string, and then use `.split()` to split your string by a sequence of numbers.

So first you can use `.join('')` to obtain:

```
"5534*52"
```

And then `.split(/(\d+)/)` to split this string on number sequences. Here `\d+` means split by (one or more) numbers, where `()` is used to keep the sequence of numbers in the resulting splitted array. After the split you will get an array looking like:

```
["", "5534", "*", "52", ""]
```

You can then use `.filter(Boolean)` to keep only the truthy values in your array. In the above array, the truthy values are the non-empty strings. After the filter you will get an array looking like:

```
["5534", "*", "52"]
```

Lastly, you can convert the string numbers into numbers, by mapping over the above array using `.map()`. If the element is a number, you can convert it to a number using the unary plus operator `+x`, otherwise, you can leave it as a string. After the map, you get your final result:

```
[5534, "*", 52]
```

See working example below:

```js
const arr = [5,5,3,4,'*',5,2];

const merged = arr.join('').split(/(\d+)/).filter(Boolean).map(x => isNaN(x) ? x : +x);
console.log(merged);
```

Comment: ah dang thats pretty amazing you did that in one line of code. Unfortunately I have no idea what is happening. Thank you though. edit: appreciate the explanation. I'll try and wrap my dome around it.

Comment: @JamesRoss sorry, took me a little while to write an explanation. I've added more details which should help clarify what the code is doing.

Comment: I'm very very thankful you took the time to explain that. I didn't even know you could chain methods like that. So cool. You rock!